# how to avoid multiple null checks, if need do something after the each check

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, null, notnull

How to avoid multiple null checks, if need do something after the each check or how best to handle these checks? java 8+

```
public void method(Object obj){
    if (Objects.nonNull(obj.getA())) {
        do something;
    }
    if (Objects.nonNull(obj.getB())) {
        do something;       
    }
    if (Objects.nonNull(obj.getC())) {
        do something;
    }
    do something;
}
```

Comment: There's no alternative to null checks in Java8. You have to do it explicitly. Anyway `obj.getA() != null` seems much simpler and succinct than what you have used above.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it idiomatically, except it does not compile.

Comment: Well, you could use some form of loop to check the elements and a lambda to handle those that are null. Whether that makes sense depends on your requirements. One thing you could try (without a custom method) is something like this (conceptually): `Arrays.asList(obj.getA(), obj.getB(), ...).stream().filter(e -> e == null).foreach(e -> /*do something*/)`.

Comment: @Thomas Please, no... :) Streams are not the answer. There are so many useless objects created there for no functional reason. And if they were, you should use Objects::nonNull as the predicate instead of creating a new lambda.

Comment: So you want to avoid something that is inherently part of your program logic? You mean you are searching for a different syntax for the same thing. If you want to know if the code itself can be optimized, in a sense that a check can truly be avoided,  then you need to provide more context: What is the code doing? What is `obj`? What is each branch doing? And so on.

Comment: @Torben yes I agree :) - that's why I added that "conceptually". The better way would be to use a plain old foreach with varargs and a single lambda. Btw, `Objects::nunNull` would be the wrong one in that case since I wanted to get only those that are null. :D

Comment: @Thomas instead of `Arrays.asList(obj.getA(), obj.getB(), ...).stream()` you can write `Stream.of(obj.getA(), obj.getB(), ...)`

Comment: @Holger yes that's what I thought but at a quick glance at the API I didn't spot the varargs version of that method so I settled for the more complex one - still it was just to convey an idea and not meant to be used as is. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on your query but you can use the Optional class from Java8 for the null check.

```
    dataType value=(dataType) Optional.of(obj).orElse(put some value);
```